# problem with response format in Groovy POST HttpRequest

Tags: xml, http, groovy

I'm tryging send XML POST request in Groovy to HttpClient and in response I would like to see also XML message. But I still see in response message in one text line, it's not xml.
Could you tell me what is wrong ?

static void request() {

```
    def body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>" +
            "<my XML request>";


    def result = HttpBuilder.configure {
        request.uri ="Ipaddress"
        request.contentType = 'application/xml'
        request.headers.id = "sadasdas1212134"
        request.body = body
    }.post();

    println result

}
```

Comment: What response message do you get? Why do you not include it in the question?

Comment: I get text response in one line all params from xml but I need message in xml